# How do I decrease the resolution on a Virtualbox client at fullscreen?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I'm running Virtualbox v4.3.8 (I just downgraded from .10 thinking that was the issue) with guest additions installed.
Host: Windows 8.1 (latest updates)
Client: Windows 7 Pro

History.  I just changed laptops to the Lenovo Yoga 2 which has a native resolution of 3200 x 1800 and my previous machine had a max resolution of 1600 x 900.  I have my work vm on an external drive, and when I brought it up it is trying to run at 3200 x 1608 and I can't read anything.  I can change the icon size and other trickery, but I'd like to set the vm guest resolution at 1600 x 900 in full screen.  Lowering the resolution in Windows just shrinks the visible window.

It seems to me like a dumb question, but my google skills have failed me.

Comment: What's the host resolution?  You should be able to set the guest to 1600x900, and then enable scale mode (host+C) . . .

Comment: Well, wow.  That worked.  I was messing with fullscreen too much and didn't try scale after changing resolution.  Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your host is a higher resolution than the guest, so when you set the guest to 1600x900, it shows in a small window.  To enable scaling in the Virtual Box window, you can use Host + C (right ctrl is the default host key in Windows).

Comment: Thanks!  I had to turn off both 2D and 3D hardware acceleration or there was serious display lag.